# .NET Core service takes time to shutdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

This is the general issue for any service created in .NET Core. I created a new SampleService (ASP.NET Core 6 Web API). I added a controller (`Ping`) with one method that returns "OK" on hitting the URL: `http://localhost/SampleService/Ping` when hosted on IIS.

In `Pingcontroller.cs` I added this code:

```
[Route("Ping")]
[HttpGet]
public string Index()
{
    return "OK";
}
```

I built the project and right-clicked on `SampleService` project and click "Publish" (under target select folder).

I then click on "Publish" that will publish required files to the folder `bin\Release\net6.0\publish` in the project's path.

Steps for the issue:

1. Copy the content of the publish folder from the project's folder path. So in your project's path go to `~\SampleService\SampleService\bin\Release\net6.0\publish`.
2. Paste the copied content to this folder location
   `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SampleService` (create the `SampleService` folder if it's not there already)
3. Open IIS and create a new application pool by the name of `SampleService` with the following properties:

   ```
   .NET CLR Version: No Managed Code
   Managed Pipeline Mode: Intergrated Mode
   ```

   Go to advanced settings, under 'Process Model', change the value of 'Idle time-out(minutes)' from default value of '20' to '0'.
4. Under "Default Web Site", right click on `SampleService` folder and click on "Convert Application", choose the app pool created in previous step.
5. Open the browser and hit the URL `http://localhost/SampleService/Ping`
6. Now in IIS, stop the `SampleService` application pool and after that start application pool again.

You will see an error dialog box on start:

[image: IIS_Error]

The reason is the `SampleService` process is still alive in task manager as shown here:

[image: SampleServiceIn TaskBar]

Any reason why the service takes a long time to shut down? It should have been closed when `SampleService` app pool is stopped

I have tried the steps which I mentioned and along with that I have also created the same `SampleService` on later versions like .NET 7 and .NET 8, just to confirm if that was some framework issue and might be resolved on later version.

I want to explore the reason to long shutdown time and resolve it.

Comment: Show us your `.csproj` file.

Comment: _"Any reason why the service takes long time to shutdown?"_ - **How** have you wired-up your ASP.NET executable to IIS? Are you using the AspNetCoreV2 ISAPI module or some other approach (e.g. ARR+Kestrel?). Where have you configured ASP.NET Core to listen for IIS hosting events? Do you have the _ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle_ installed?

Comment: <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Comment: Microsoft.net 6.015  - windows server Hosting is installed. After publish as mentioned in above steps, I have deployed the application files to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SampleService and hosted it on IIS.

Comment: I doubt this is a machine dependent issue, since I didn't experience the same on all machines in the past. But to debug and reveal the culprit will be difficult. If your company has support contracts with Microsoft, time to use them to open support tickets.

Comment: This same issue does not occur when I tested on system having IIS version 10.0.22621.1, the application stop immediately on stopping the app pool where as on the system having IIS version 10.0.19041.1, the issue is observed.
I assume this issue could be because of IIS and might have been resolved in its later version.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. This has nothing to do with ASP.NET Core, I also get this error when testing the default DefaultAppPool. As long as this Site is accessed, you will encounter this error code 80070425 if you restart it immediately after stopping. If the site is not visited, it will not be encountered.

**My Test Steps**

*1. Reproduce the issue in IIS.*

*2. Guess if this is related to IIS Management, then use appcmd to test. Verified this is expected behavior.*

[image]

*3. Search the error code, and find explanation below.*

[image]

[ERROR_SERVICE_CANNOT_ACCEPT_CTRL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-controlserviceexa#return-value)

[image]

**Summary**

Obviously, this proves that the application pool is stopping and cannot be started immediately because it is in the `SERVICE_STOP_PENDING` state, so it is recommended to wait for 2 seconds before performing the next step.

Comment: On system having IIS version 10.0.19041.1, even if I wait for more than 2 seconds it is still the same issue(the application do not stop on stopping the app pool). And the on the system having IIS version 10.0.22621.1, the application service will stop on stopping the app pool and does not throw any error when started again immediately(even within 2s of time)

Comment: Hi @rahul, When I say 2 seconds, I just mean a very short period of time. In your environment, it may be 5 seconds or 10 seconds. As long as the stop operation is completed, you will not encounter problems when starting again.

Comment: @rahul You can follow the picture or link I provided for the win32 API instructions on the use of ERROR_SERVICE_CANNOT_ACCEPT_CTRL. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Jason

I understand that it is an expected behavior and the steps you mentioned were helpful in confirming that.
As per my analysis the same issue when tested on windows 11 with version 22H2, it is not reproducible. So it is based on system and not in our control.  

Thanks for the information.